# Locate and select web element in Chrome?

Tags: chrome

I frequently visit webpages that have built-in search boxes. I'm searching for products, articles, and what have you.

Is there a fast and effective way to find a search box (or indeed another element) using Chrome?

I would imagine a Chrome Extension that automatically finds search boxes on a page, using the source code. Most search boxes will have an element identifier similar to "search", "find", etc. With a keyboard command the box could be selectable.

Another alternative I thought of, is to look at the search box and see if it contains a placeholder text, like "Search here …". If I then use *Find* and look for the word "Search", is there a Chrome keyboard command to *select* that element (the search box)?

---

*Note: Using Google Search and directing it to search the website in question is not what I'm looking for. Furthermore, this is not about the Developer View in Chrome.*